# Catch only a left clicks on links

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

[We are](http://coyod.com) using event `click` to catch click on links and load content via ajax.
But event happens also on right mouse and wheel clicks.
How to process only left?
*confused*

```
// jquery.coyod-engine-0.5.0.js
$(document).click(function(e){
        
        var t = $(e.target);            
        if(t.hasClass('aj'))
        {               
            
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            showContent(t.attr('href'));                            
            return false;               
        }
        
        return true;
        
    });
```

Comment: Thank you guys, sorry for inattention  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throw in a check at the start of you function which checks if the left button was used

```
//left == 0, middle == 1, right == 2
if (e.button != 0) return true;
else {
  //whatever
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add this at the begining of your callback:

```
if (e.button != 0) return true;
```